Who pays the recruiter exactly, the freelance developer, or the hiring company?
This might be a dumb question, but I am trying to get into doing freelance work as a software engineer, and working directly with recruiters is new to me. I often read that the recruiters will charge somewhere between 10-20% of the annual salary for the position that they filled.
What I am just not sure about, is if this will be charged to the candidate (as a fee for finding a gig for them), or if this will be charged to the hiring company (as a fee for filling the position)? Both seem fair reasons to have some service fee associated with it.

Might you be confusing very different things. Not merely 'pretty much' but clearly, 'all' recruiters not merely 'on platforms like Indeed' but anywhere, ever, will be hired and paid by companies to fill the position. Have you any doubts about that? Recruiters should always invoice the company. If you're a freelance, how could there be any question of 'salary…', annual or otherwise? Do you have any friends or acquaintances who work freelance?

It all depends on who actually hires the recruiter. Most companies hire the recruiter to find good candidates and they pay the recruiter. Some individuals hire a recruiter to find open positions that fit their requirements, and they pay the recruiter.

Okay interesting, thanks for the response. So pretty much all recruiters on platforms like Indeed, would be hired and paid by companies to fill the position. And I should not expect them to take a cut of the annual salary that I invoice to a company once I found a project. But rather, they will invoice the company separately for the filled position.

Really, David? I was an active freelance for something more than 20 years and I never once heard any faint suggestion of a freelance paying a recruiter.
Can you Post details of how your arrangements worked in recruitment generally and freelancing particularly?

@RobbieGoodwin It is not common, but it has happened. I have not done it.

Really, David? Why not show how that helps here?

The best way would be to compare to dating. Many people use the free dating apps. Others pay a nominal fee dating app. Some people pay thousands of dollars to a match maker who goes out to find the "perfect" match. From what I have heard, the people who pay a recruiter generally are looking for quite high paying positions.
